# How do I remove a package with a failing scriptlet in Fedora 32?

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm, dnf

I'm trying to remove the `emacs` package from my Fedora 32 system using the `dnf remove emacs` command, however when I remove it this happens:

```
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1 
  Running scriptlet: emacs-1:26.3-2.fc32.x86_64                             1/1 
error: %preun(emacs-1:26.3-2.fc32.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 2

Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package emacs
  Verifying        : emacs-1:26.3-2.fc32.x86_64                             1/1 

Failed:
  emacs-1:26.3-2.fc32.x86_64                                                    

Error: Transaction failed
```

The `emacs` package is subsequently **not** removed. How might I go about removing a package with a failing scriptlet, preferably using dnf? (as opposed to using rpm directly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is already described e.g. here: https://serverfault.com/questions/613256/yum-error-in-preun-scriptlet-when-removing-packages

YUM has been replaced by DNF but this option remains the same.

`dnf --setopt=tsflags=noscripts` or `rpm --noscripts` should to the trick.

Comment: or edit the config file /etc/dnf/dnf.conf